Is there is a way to exempt apps (e.g. termux) from Doze in Android 14?
Since Android 14, I'm no longer able to log into my phone remotely via a reverse tunnel to a server with a static IP.  It appears that Doze is the underlying issue; it stops termux, which stops the sshd child process, so the tunnel goes away, and it doesn't come back, despite my having scheduled (in termux-land) a check-and-restore process every few minutes.  It does not help to turn off battery optimizations or to enable wake-lock.
Is there is a way to exempt termux (for example) from Doze in Android 14 without rooting the phone?
